# Editing or creating a build definition shows an error when opening the Process tab

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013, tfsbuild

When I edit an existing Build Definition, or try to create a new one, I'm consistently greeted by an error message:

> (X) Team Foundation Error:
>
> Type `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.ClientBasicAuthCredential` in assembly `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a` is not marked as serializable.

[image]

And it is not possible to edit any of the build parameters on the Process tab as a result.

I have tried uninstalling the latest Visual Studio update, repairing Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate and then reinstalling Visual Studio again to no avail.

Comment: Did [this help](http://brian.minisi.net/2014/01/21/basicauthcredential-not-serializable/) at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that clearing the credentials to your TFS server from [both the Windows and the Generic section of the Windows Credentials Manager](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/remove-stored-passwords-certificates-and-other-credentials) and then restarting Visual Studio will resolve the issue.

[image]

I've raised the bug with Microsoft. Thank you [Brian Minisi for the tip that lead to the solution](http://brian.minisi.net/2014/01/21/basicauthcredential-not-serializable/#comment-628).

Comment: I'd suggest potentially elaborating on this answer, it's been flagged as low quality for being primarily a link-only answer.

Comment: Isn't much more to tell. Open Credentials Manager, Find Credential, Delete it, Restart Visual Studio. Added a picture instead :@>